# Transform XML nodes into attributes of the parent and merge duplicate nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform an XML feed with XSLT to:

- Merge repeated nodes into a comma-delimited list of one node e.g. `<section>`
- Transform all child elements of each  into attributes
- Transform the enclosure/url attribute into "image_url" attribute of

Here is the XML:

```
<item>
    <guid>XX-12345</guid>
    <link>http://www.stackoverflow.com.au</link>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="0" url="http://www.stackoverflow.com.au/images/image.jpg"/>
    <description>Description of my article</description>
    <pubDate>2015-05-13T12:05:33.620000+10:00</pubDate>
    <section>test</section>
    <section>other</section>
    <section>sub-other</section>
    <section>2015</section>
    <section>05</section>
    <category>parentX:childA:category text</category>
    <category>parentY:childB:category text, with commas</category>
    <category>parentZ:childC:category text</category>
</item>
```

And this is the desired output:

```
<item guid="XX-12345" link="http://www.stackoverflow.com.au" title="This is the title" image_url="http://www.stackoverflow.com.au/images/image.jpg" description="Description of my article" pubDate="2015-05-13T12:05:33.620000+10:00" section="'test','other','sub-other','2015','05'" category="'parentX:childA:category text','parentY:childB:category text, with commas','parentZ:childC:category text'"></item>
```

This XSLT got me most of the way, but but I can't work out how to create the comma delimited list of repeated nodes (this results in `<item section="05">` for the multiple sections in the above XML):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="channel">
    <channel>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </channel>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <item>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'enclosure'">
                <xsl:attribute name="image_url">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>        
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 the main template for `item` could be:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name(.)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::enclosure">
                    <xsl:attribute name="image_url" select="@url"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"
                      select="if (current-group()[2]) then current-group()/concat('''', ., '''') else ."
                      separator=","/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```